# twitter search OR operator ignored?

Tags: search, twitter

I may be missing something completely obvious, but if I try a twitter search for "bear" "paddington" OR "station" "paddington", like so:

https://twitter.com/search?q=bear%20paddington%20OR%20station%20paddington&src=typd

I only get results for Paddington bear.

Strangely enough, if I switch the terms in each clause:

https://twitter.com/search?q=paddington%20bear%20OR%20paddington%20station&src=typd

I only get results for Paddington station (?!).

I'm seeing the same when submitting these queries using the REST API.

What I'm looking for is tweets with
(paddington AND bear) OR (paddington AND station)

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Your search term is essentially searching for `bear AND (paddington OR station) AND paddington` so you will get the results you are seeing.

What you are trying to search for is `paddington AND (bear OR station)` so https://twitter.com/search?q=paddington%20bear%20OR%20station&src=typd should achieve that

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work.  
  
I guess this means that for twitter search, the OR operator takes precedence over AND ...  
  
(haven't seen that before, everwhere AND takes precedence AFAIK)  
  
edit: it looks like I can control precedence with parentheses (!):  
  
https://twitter.com/search?q=%28paddington%20bear%29%20OR%20%28paddington%20station%29&src=typd  
  
(nowhere in the docs, but it works..)

Comment: 2nd edit: it works for the online search, but not for the API :-(

Comment: 3rd edit: the suggested query works with the search API (so
`q=paddington bear OR station`  
(@ade: voted your answer up, just don't have enough rep points yet..)